# Fluent NHibernate memory leak

Tags: nhibernate, memory-leaks, fluent-nhibernate

I'm pulling my hair over what seems to be a memory leak but I cannot find the cause :(

I built an application on my own PC, pretty heavy beast with alot of memory, so I never realised my process consumed so much memory. I only realised after releasing the code to a production environment with limited memory.

I use quite a few different technologies and patterns, including WCF, but I have now come to the point where I stripped most of the code to find out what consumes so much memory...

Here is the most simplified version of the app, 1 entity, 1 mapping, and a simple procedure that retrieves from the DB, while it's running, I can see the the process in the task manager growing endlessly:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var i = 0;

            while ( i < 1000000 )
            {
                ISession session = BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
                ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
                var users = session.Query< User >().ToList();
                transaction.Commit();
                transaction.Dispose();
                transaction = null;
                session.Dispose();
                session = null;
                Console.WriteLine( users.Count );
                users = null;
                i++;
            }
        }

        private static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database( MsSqlConfiguration
                               .MsSql2008
                               .ConnectionString( "Data Source=SEB-PC\\SEBPC;Initial Catalog=Nice;Integrated Security=True" ) )
                .Mappings( m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<User>() )
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMap : ClassMap< User >
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id( x => x.Id ).UnsavedValue( Guid.Empty );
            Map( x => x.FirstName )
                .Length( 50 )
                .Not.Nullable();
            Map( x => x.LastName )
                .Length( 50 )
                .Not.Nullable();
            Map( x => x.Email )
                .Length( 254 )
                .Not.Nullable()
                .Unique();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I got the 3rd party DLL's using nuget, and the versions are the following:

- FluentNHibernate: 1.3.0.733
- Iesi.Collections: 1.0.1.0
- NHibernate: 3.3.1.4000

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I have been googling all over the place for over a week now :(

Thanks!

Seb :)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, my apologies.
Originally, this is part of a full application with 1 WCF host, 1 client site, 2 clients console apps/windows services.
But as I said, I have stripped all the code to find out what is causing the leak.
Now I am left with this little piece of code, and I do an iteration on purpose to "simulate" people interacting with the site and requesting data from the DB, and I still see the same behaviour, the process grows and grows as long as new sessions are created (and even disposed)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm such a noob, indeed I should not create a new session factory every time but use an existing one. What lead me into the wrong direction is that originally my code is hosted in a WCF service, in which I thought I had to create a new factory every time.

I have now made sure only 1 factory exists throughout the code and the memory consumption is stable.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating 1000000 Hibernate session object, why do you want to create these many session objects just create 1 session object and do run your query using just 1 session object.

Comment: I do this on purpose to test the process, I iterate a million times, but each time the session is disposed, and so should the resources...
Even without this loop, the process will eat more memory, and every time someone retrieves data from the DB, the process grows, why?